# Integrate two sets of Data and check similarity

Tags: integration, statistics, dynamic-programming

I have the following CSV Data
I used Excel Charts to plot the Data

I want to compare these Data with other Data, in another word i want to comapre 2 curves and check the similarity between them

in my case
$$
y = f(x) = \text{Value | x=Time}
$$

i found the following formula

$$
\% \text{ error} = \frac{\sum{||{f(x)-g(x)}}||}{\sum\sqrt{(x_{i+1}-x_{i})^2+(y_{i+1}-y_{i})^2}}
$$

is this Formula correct ?

are $x_{i} \text{ and } y_{i}$ the `Value` or simply the `Indices` that are in my case `Time`?

what if the both functions have different `x` or `Time` but they have/follow the same trend ?

i'm using python for programming

[image: CSV Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[source]](http://www.anybodytech.com/fileadmin/downloads/ComputerSimulationISB2011_AnyBody_Comparing_calculated_and_measured.pdf)

in this case instead we use integration we sum the data because we have only points

$$v_{mm} = \frac{1}{stop-start} \sum{f(x)^2} $$
$$v_{cc} = \frac{1}{stop-start} \sum{g(x)^2} $$

$$\text{error % }  C = \sqrt{M^2+P^2} 
$$